# Will disabling Hyper-V delete my existing Hyper-V VM's?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I basically want to install VirtualBox but to install it I have to disable Hyper-V . But I already have a couple of VM's in Hyper-V that I don't want to get deleted.

So if I disable Hyper-V in windows feature, install virtual box do my stuff and after uninstalling virtual box I enable Hyper-V again , will my older Hyper-V VM's still be intact or they would get deleted or corrupted ??

Comment: You can also just disable the Hyper-V hypervisor, maybe that’s a more suitable way for you?

Comment: You can use Export\Import as backup purpose. For how to export and import virtual machines, you can refer to the following link:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/deploy/export-and-import-virtual-machines

Comment: “I basically want to install VirtualBox but to install it I have to disable Hyper-V” - If you are running the current version of Windows and VirtualBox that isn’t exactly true.